# FirstOrDefault on IEnumerable with non-nullable contents

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I need to return the first element of an `IEnumerable`. And if the `IEnumerable` is empty I return a special value.

The code for this can look like this :

```
return myEnumerable.FirstOrDefault() ?? mySpecialValue;
```

This is nice and work fine until `myEnumerable`contains nullable stuffs.

In this case, the best I get is :

```
return myEnumerable.Any() ? myEnumerable.First() : mySpecialValue;
```

But here I have multiple enumeration of `myEnumerable` !

How can I do it ? I prefer to avoid to have to catch any exception.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the overload of [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify your fallback value. Then you also don't need `FirstOrDefault` but you an use `First` safely:

```
return myEnumerable.DefaultIfEmpty(mySpecialValue).First();
```

Comment: Thanks ! don't know about this one ! Is this always the way to do it or the `return myEnumerable.FirstOrDefault() ?? mySpecialValue;` is prefered when available ?

Comment: The two aren't quite the same even with nullable types. `myEnumerable.DefaultIfEmpty(mySpecialValue).First()` will always return `mySpecialValue` if the sequence is empty, but can also return `null` if the first element is `null`. `myEnumerable.FirstOrDefault() ?? mySpecialValue` will return `mySpecialValue` if either the sequence is empty or the first value use `null`. This can be better or worse depending on the use case.

Comment: Thanks JonHanna, I haven't see this.